# How to hot swap .twig or .pebble files in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pebble

So I've been using spring boot dev tools as a means to hot swap files when I make small changes. The problem I'm having right now is I have been using .pebble files which are located in the resources/templates file in my spring project. Dev tools was working initially with my html files but when I switched to using .pebble it stopped. I tried doing the following where I added this line of code in the application.properties file but it didnt work:
`spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=static/**`.
Is there a way I can get dev tools to look specifically for .pebble files or just any file type in that folder and when there are changes hot swap them? Here is my folder config if that helps. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if pebble cache is enabled ? By default it is. You can disable it in your application.properties with the following value:

pebble.cache=false